# ModuleNoFound Error ,while using num2words

Tags: python, django

I successfully installed num2words with

```
pip install num2words
```

in my django project.
when I import it by as follows

```
from num2words import num2words
```

and use it as

num2words(amount)

I am getting error

```
from num2words import num2words
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'num2words'
```

I installed it inside virtual env properly here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Do you use a local environment?

Comment: I am installing inside virtual env. All other libraries are working fine like reportlab etc ,not sure why this specific not working

Comment: @Jason: but you did install it in the virtualenv? not at the "global" pip?

Comment: if not done yet, you should FIRST activate your local virtual environement and then re-install that package. and then check with `pip list` command.

Comment: I uploaded screenshot ,clearly I installed inside virtual Env

Comment: @cizario ,@Willem Van Onsem I uploaded screenshot indicating clearly ,its installed inside virtual env

Comment: What ide are you using? See if you are using this virtualenv in the interpreter configuration

Comment: no its not in interpreter configuration , i am using VSCode

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before with numpy.

You need to check that the module `num2words` is compatible with your version of python in the virtual environment.

Also, if you haven't tried already, uninstall then reinstall.